# ASP.NET C# GridView paging options

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

[image: Error message im getting]

I am currently attempting to make gridview load 1 question at a time, when I set the paging to 1 it gives me this error.

Also using the VS15 SQL server

Comment: Please include the code as text in your question, not as a picture. We don't program with pictures. It's hard to copy/paste your code, and hard to index text for searching.

Comment: Sorry, i mainly did it to display the error I was getting. I won't do it again

Comment: A picture is fine as a supplement, but you need to include the actual code and actual error as text in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an SqlAdapter instead of SqlDataReader. The reason is because you cannot Page back if you use SqlDataReader. SqlAdapter supports bidirectional traversal.

You were not using a Data table to retrieve the results form the select query. Use this instead

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
       loadgrid(); 
    }
 }
 private void loadgrid() {
 con.Open(); 
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [Question] ORDER BY NEWID()"; 
 cmd.Connection = con;
 SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 ad.Fill(dt);
 GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
 GridView1.AllowPaging = true; 
 GridView1.DataBind();

 }
```

Comment: SqlDataAdapter rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

I've gotten this far, what would you write instead of "ExecuteReader"?

Comment: SqlDataAdapter rd = new SqlAdapter(cmd);

Comment: I ended up with another error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

All this is new to me.

Comment: could you share the loadGridMethod ?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                loadgrid();
            }

        }

        private void loadgrid()
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 4 * FROM [Question] ORDER BY NEWID()";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            GridView1.DataSource = ad;
            GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            GridView1.DataBind();
  
        }

Is this of any use? :)

Comment: You are a saint, it is working just as intended now. Thanks a whole bunch!

Comment: No worries mate :-)